# How to filter accounts list according to the direction that mobile is pointed at?

Tags: android, ios, backend, mobile-development

I have many locations of accounts saved in database with their latitude and longitude and theses accounts are sent from backend and I display them as a list.
I want to point my mobile in a specific direction and only accounts in this direction will be displayed on screen.
I tried to use the compass and sent its degree to backend but it wasn't accurate and the accounts displayed are not the real accounts that exist in the direction I want.

Comment: Hi, Eman. It would be helpful you could provide an example the GPS coordinates of both the expected and incorrect accounts. You would need to provide the GPS coordinates of your mobile device and the compass angle. That may help others diagnose your issue. Also, is the backend something you wrote? Or an existing third-party system? One last question; are you depending on the client application to do the filtering or the backend?

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.